# Passing the paraphrase as an option to encrypt/decrypt command in solaris

Tags: encryption, bash-scripting, solaris, password-management, decryption

Can we pass the paraphrase as an option to the encrypt/decrypt command without being prompted for stdin?
encrypt -a aes  [-i input-file] [-o output-file]

Comment: Looks like you may want the `-k` option: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5165/encrypt-1.html#scrolltoc

Comment: But -k option works for encryption with keys but i'm specifically looking for passing paraphrase in the command itself

Comment: Since it specifically uses [getpassphrase(3C)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5168/getpassphrase-3c.html#REFMAN3Agetpassphrase-3c) it seems you have no choice but to use a tool like [tag:sshpass] or [tag:expect], both of which you'll need to build or install.